# update computer from mysql server

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have been working on this for hours I am sure it is something simple I am missing. I have a remote server that gets updated form from another pc once the sever gets updated I would like my PC to get the changes from the server I cant seem to get it done the closest I have been is shown below any help would be greatly appreciated. Connection string no issue just trying to update the PC database to Match the server database

```
 Sub updateRecord()
    Try
        Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection("server=" & My.Settings.ServerIPAddress & ";user id=root;password=T@ttleT@le102;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=pmdatabase")
        dbConnection.Open()
        Using Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblpmdata", dbConnection)
            Using Table As New DataTable
                Adapter.Fill(Table) 'test to see if table is correct
                Adapter.Fill(Me.PmdatabaseDataSet.tblpmdata)
                Me.PmdatabaseDataSet.AcceptChanges()
                Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.PmdatabaseDataSet)
                MsgBox(Table.Rows.Count)only shows 5 records when the server has 8 records
            End Using
        End Using

        dbConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```